# Python ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, numpy, svd

I am doing SVD and when I try to run my code I get the following error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (375, 375) (375, 500)

I am using an image with size (500, 375)

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
from Image import new
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import svd

im = Image.open("lake.tif")
pix = im.load()
im.show()
r, g, b = im.split()
R = np.array(r.getdata())
R.shape = (500, 375)
Ur, Sr, VrT = svd(R.T, full_matrices=False)
R1 = Ur * diag(Sr) * VrT
```

Answer (score 7):

You are doing component wise product. Either make those things matrices or use:

```
 R1 = np.dot(Ur, np.dot(diag(SR), VrT))
```

or use something like:

```
Ur, Sr, VrT = map(np.asmatrix, (Ur, diag(Sr), Vrt))
R1 = Ur * Sr * VrT
```

Which is much cleaner if you do a lot of matrix products (like in this line), otherwise arrays are typically preferable since they are the base type. If you prefer you can of course also just call `np.asmatrix` on each itself.

Comment: you should probably describe how to transform a `ndarray` into a `matrix` and explain that for `matrix` objects, multiplication works as expected...